# JQgrid cant load in quirks' mode IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, quirks-mode

I have a web page, that has links which redirect to some other webpages that should open in a new window. When i click on any of these links, the new webpage loads in quirks mode and the JQGrid does not show up. However, when i refresh the same page, the grid loads up fine. Any Help ?

[image: The error message]

I have also tried changing the doctype, but nothing works

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<!--  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> -->
```

before the doctype tags, have

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<jsp:useBean id="header" scope="request" class="Abtclass" /> 
<jsp:useBean id="footer" scope="request" class="Abjclass" />
```

right now, the first thing inside my  tag is

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: *"...before the doctype tags, have..."* The doctype should always be the *very first* thing in your page. That said, the things you show wouldn't output anything but whitespace to the client, and so shouldn't matter, but still it's best not to leave yourself open to editing errors. Put the doctype on line 1.

Comment: thanks T.J. I did not put the entire webpage here as it is quite long. i thought that the problem must lie in the head type or the doctype since the webpage loads perfectly fine in chrome !

Comment: I didn't say anything about posting the whole page here.

Comment: by the way, which of the two doctypes do you think would be better ?

Comment: The only doctype I recommend unless you have a ***really, really, really good reason*** for using something else is `<!doctype html>` (the doctype for HTML5). The only exception is if someone is holding you down and making you wear the hairshirt that is XHTML, and if they do, give me a call and I'll try to get 'em off you. There's no reason to use XHTML in 2014, and a lot of reasons not to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found a fix

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

**FOLLOW UP:**

why does this not work

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

I am using IE9. Also, note that the error does not show up in chrome at all ! even without the above meta tag fix.